# How do I autocomplete a link to a node?

Tags: 7, entities

In my Drupal 7 site I created a custom search form with an autocomplete field that shows the node title. I want the node title point to the node page. For this I am using the following code in a custom module.

```
function autocomplete_engine($text) {
    $results = array();

    $result = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n')
    ->condition('title', db_like($text) . '%', 'LIKE');
    $nodes = $result->execute();

    foreach ($nodes as $row) {
        $node = node_load($row->nid);
        $output = '';
        $output .= l($row->title,'node/'.$row->nid);
        $results[$row->title] = $output;
        }

    $result_term = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
    ->fields('t')
    ->condition('name ', db_like($text) . '%', 'LIKE');
    $terms = $result_term->execute();

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $out = '';
        $out .= $term->name;
        $results[$term->tid] = check_plain($out);
        }

    drupal_json_output($results);
 }
```

When I click on the node title nothing happens. How do I redirect when the result is a node and not a term name?

Comment: check below link for drupal custom autocomplete https://www.webomelette.com/how-to-create-autocomplete-widget-drupal-7

Comment: Autocomplete result showing but I want redirect result on click there page.

Comment: It's working when I change my theme to Bartik .It is override by bootstrap.